# How do I Iterate through a combobox options without clicking on one?

Tags: interface

I see this done in a a lot of videos ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yLBNwmxxvI&t=111), for example) and was wondering what keyboard shortcut is used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through dropdown list items by holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling with the mouse **wheel** <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd>while hovering over the gui item in question.